# Efficiently filling a FloatBuffer from part of a ByteBuffer

Tags: java, opengl, jogl, floatbuffer, mappedbytebuffer

Currently I am filling a FloatBuffer from a Mapped Byte Buffer in the following way:

```
/**
 * The vertex lump (Lump 3) is an array of coordinates of all the vertices (corners)    of brushes in the map geometry. 
 * Each vertex is a Vector of 3 floats (x, y, and z), giving 12 bytes per vertex. 
 * @author Jurian
 *
 */
public class VertexLump extends Lump {
    public final FloatBuffer vertexes;

    /**
     * @param buffer Little-Endian buffer with actual data
     * @param bsp Used for referencing the header with position and length of vertex data
     */
    public VertexLump(MappedByteBuffer buffer, ValveBSP bsp) {
        super(buffer, bsp.headers[LumpType.LUMP_VERTEXES.index]);
        //MappedByteBuffer is set to correct position in super()
        vertexes = FloatBuffer.allocate(header.filelen / (Buffers.SIZEOF_FLOAT));
        for(int i = 0; i < vertexes.capacity(); i++) {
            vertexes.put(buffer.getFloat());
        }
        vertexes.flip();
    }
}
```

But I have a suspicion that there is a better way to do this, instead of looping over all positions. There can be quite a few vertexes in the buffer (a maximum of 65536).

This seems to work:

```
public VertexLump(MappedByteBuffer buffer, ValveBSP bsp) {
    super(buffer, bsp.headers[LumpType.LUMP_VERTEXES.index]);
    vertexes = buffer.asFloatBuffer();
    vertexes.limit(header.filelen / Buffers.SIZEOF_FLOAT);
}
```

However will this function in OpenGL send too much data to the GPU? Or just from the current position to the limit?

```
gl.glBufferData(GL3.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexes.limit(), vertexes, GL3.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

Comment: Why are you copying the data?  I would use `buffer.asFloatBuffer()`

Comment: @PeterLawrey Because I don't want to copy the entire bytebuffer but only the bytes from `header.fileofs` to `header.fileofs + header.filelen`.

Comment: buffer.slice().asFloatBuffer()?

Comment: I think you misread the question; you don't need to copy the data at all (not even a portion of it)

Comment: When I use `buffer.asFloatBuffer()`, the new `FloatBuffer` also contains all the bytes that come after the data I need. I'd like to send the `FloatBuffer` to OpenGL, with only the vertex data.

Comment: Can I use `vertexes.limit(header.filelen / Buffers.SIZEOF_FLOAT)` to stop JOGL from reading too many bytes?

Comment: JOGL takes into account the position and the limit of a buffer.

Comment: @PeterLawrey If you want you can add your first comment as an answer and I will accept it.